# What does “Spaß muss eben sein” mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase

I am reading a fragment of *[Ganz unten](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ganz_unten)* and it contains the sentence:

> Spaß muss eben sein.

It is Ali’s reaction when customers throw ashtrays on the floor and he has to clean them up. They laugh, and Ali writes the above sentence in the book.

When I translate it literally, I get:

> Fun must be precise.

That does not seem to be what it means. So I’m wondering what it actually means.

Comment: Just wondering how you came up with "precise". The adverbs "precisely" or "exactly" do make sense (not in this context though), but if a dictionary suggests "precise" as an adjective, it's probably not a good one.

Comment: @Em1 Pretty sure it's an attempt of translating 'eben' which is much closer to 'just' in the example.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We’ll get to the role of *eben* in a moment, but for now let’s consider the sentence without it:

> Spaß muss sein.

Its meaning is rather clear: literally *fun must be,* idiomatically *fun is necessary.*

Now we add *eben.* It is a word like *just:* It can have a concise meaning but it is often *just* added to sentence for added effect. In this case, it is kind of like saying:

> Well, some people just *have* to have fun.

In the end, it’s Wallraff’s reaction to being mocked. There’s an implicit sigh in the sentence and some impicit eye-rolling. All of this is added by the *eben.*

Answer (score -1):

A more literal translation would be "Fun just has to be" or "Fun simply has to be".